# Formating file changes encoding on Redhat system

Tags: redhat, file-format, windows-1252

I have a bash script which extract data from an oracle database. I use spool to extract data. After extraction I format the file by removing and replacing some characters. My problem is after formating the files are in ANSI encoding instead of ut8.

1. Extraction with spool. The file is utf8
2. Format with cat and tr command and redirect in another file. This file is ansi.

The same process works fine on Aix system. I try iconv but it doesnt work. Do you please have an idea why the encoding changes from utf8 to ansi ? How to correct it please ?

Comment: I'm afraid you have (unintentionally) damaged your own file. Please provide more details. Start with `echo $NLS_LANG`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. $NLS_LANG is FRENCH_FRANCE.UTF8

Comment: So far so good. Now please edit your original post and quote the 'formatting' that causes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consequently use either ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8. In the latter case, don't use `tr` as it doesn't (yet?) support multi-byte characters, use `sed` instead (e.g `sed 's/deletethis//g'`).

**ISO-8859-1:**

```
export LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.ISO-8859-1
export NLS_LANG=French_France.WE8ISO8859P1

# fetch data from Oracle, emulated by the following line
echo 'âêîôû' >test.latin1 # 5 bytes (+lineend)

# perform formatting, eg:
sed 's/ê/[e-circumflex]/g' test.latin1

# or the same with hex-codes:
sed $'s/\xea/[e-circumflex]/g' test.latin1
```

**UTF-8:**

```
export LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8
export NLS_LANG=French_France.AL32UTF8

# fetch data from Oracle, emulated by the following line
echo 'âêîôû' >test.utf8 # 10 bytes (+lineend)

# perform formatting, eg:
sed 's/ê/[e-circumflex]/g' test.utf8

# or the same with hex-codes:
sed $'s/\xc3\xaa/[e-circumflex]/g' test.utf8
```

Note: no conversion (`iconv`, `recode`, etc) is required, just make sure `NLS_LANG` and `LC_CTYPE` are compatible. (Also, your terminal(emulator) should be set accordingly; for PuTTY it is Configuration/Category/Window/Translation/Remote-character-set.)

**Original answer:**

I cannot tell what's wrong with the formatting you perform, but here is a method to damage the utf8-encoded text:

```
$ echo 'ÁRVÍZTŰRŐ TÜKÖRFÚRÓGÉP' | iconv -f iso-8859-2 -t utf-8 | xxd
00000000: c381 5256 c38d 5a54 c5b0 52c5 9020 54c3  ..RV..ZT..R.. T.
00000010: 9c4b c396 5246 c39a 52c3 9347 c389 500a  .K..RF..R..G..P.

$ echo 'ÁRVÍZTŰRŐ TÜKÖRFÚRÓGÉP' | iconv -f iso-8859-2 -t utf-8 | tr -d $'\200-\237' | xxd
00000000: c352 56c3 5a54 c5b0 52c5 2054 c34b c352  .RV.ZT..R. T.K.R
00000010: 46c3 52c3 47c3 500a                      F.R.G.P.
```

Here the `tr -d $'\200-\237'` part deleted half of the utf8-sequences (c381 became c3, c590 became c5), rendering the text unusable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Here is the format I do : cat File | tr -d '\n' |tr -d '\r' | tr '°' ' '  | tr -d ' ' | tr -d 'Â' | grep -v '^$' | iconv -f ISO8859-1 -t UTF-8>File.out